# Complex object mapping in Android

Tags: java, android, orm, android-room

I'm dabbling in the `Android Room` persistence library, and I have this object that is a result of a `JSON` parse:

```
@Entity
public class Cluster {
  @PrimaryKey
  private int id;
  private boolean is_up;
  private ClusterStatus status;
  private ClusterLoad load;
  private List<Server> servers = null;
  private UserQueries user_queries;
}
```

Example of a ClusterStatus `Object` (getters and setters omitted for brevity), to show that `TypeConverter` isn't helpful:

```
public class ClusterStatus {
    private boolean isOnline;
    private String name;
    private int upTime;
}
```

Do I map all these inner `Objects` as separate `Entities`?
How do I map a `List` of `Objects` properly? (I've read the Doc but didn't get why the annotations go the way they go)
Maybe you can advise me some other ORM, that handles these relations better?

Comment: I have posted an answer, Have a look!

Answer (score 0):

> Use TypeConverters

**Make a TypeConverter class like this :**

(This example is for Date, you can similarly make for other Objects)

```
public class DateConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date toDate(Long timestamp) {
        return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long toTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

**Add TypeConverter in RoomDatabase class like this:**

```
@Database(entities = {TaskEntry.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(DateConverter.class)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase 
{

...
...

}
```

> **Official Documentation :**

- [TypeConverter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverter)
- [TypeConverters](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/TypeConverters)

Comment: Thank you, but type converters are only useful if you can represent the converted object as a primitive type. Which is the case with Date, but not applicable to my objects. Added examples to the question.